# mysqli prepared statement get_result()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When i use `get_result()` the code will stop, this is my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb,$passdb,$datadb);
if(!$conn){ 
    die(print($errormsg)); }
$ris = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='?' ;");
$ris->bind_param("s" , $user);
$ris->execute();
$result = $ris->get_result();
echo $result->error;
$ris1 = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

`echo $result->error;` is empty.

**SOLVED**
Error in SQL Query

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because when working with prepared statements, you don't need to write quotes for strings, dates and so on. The bind_param method does it automatically for you.

Also remove the ';' at the end of the sentence.

Comment: i change it, but i have ever this bug...

Comment: Put the code inside a try/catch block, then echo the exception message

Comment: try {
            $result = $ris->get_result();
           } catch(Exception $effe){
               echo $effe->getMessage();
           }
I try to do it, but it print anything

Comment: Try then to check if the statement was created. After prepare, check if $ris === FALSE.

Comment: if($ris === FALSE) <---- it was false, so the prepare was created

Comment: @Carbos: NO, if it's FALSE it isn't created, you have an error in your sentence:  if ($stmt === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception("Error: " . $conn->error);
        }

Comment: yes, i've tried it, but it doesn't tell me anything... the page stop in this line: $result = $ris->get_result(); and it doesn't print anything after this line...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $ris = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=?");
```

When you are working with prepared statements, normaly you don't use any `'`  when declaring placeholders.

Comment: i do it, but i have ever this bug...

Comment: what does **var_dump($ris1);** print?

Comment: nothing... it is empty